# CSS overflow: auto by 'touching' bottom div

Tags: javascript, html, css, overflow, responsive

I want to make a div scrollable when its touching the bottom div.
I tried this:

```
margin-bottom:30px;
position: relative;
overflow: auto;
```

but it didn't work.
I created a fiddle tho show you my problem: 
https://jsfiddle.net/wp3wvuj2/1/

For explanation: When you type in in a input field a new field is added to the div (This function is simplified). I want that before the input fields touch the element below (the START-div) it gets scrollable (overflow: auto).

Somebody have an idea?

Edit: 
I noticed that nobody understands my problem.
I'll try to explain it better:
I have list where players add their names. The list has minimum 4 players maximum ∞.

The start buttonis placed at the bottom. The problem is in a iphone 5 it looks like this:
[image: iPhone 5 View]

And now if i would add another player input field it would Overlap with the START-Button. Thats the reason why I want it scrollable now. I already get that work with a fixed height, but i want it responsive!

Because on a iPad for example it looks like this:
[image: view on iPad]

And I want prevent an overlap with the start button like this:
[image]

So it should get scrollable before it overlaps (dependent on the display size).

Comment: At the moment typing anything duplicates an input field. From what I can tell, you just want the input field you're typing in to scroll once enough content is in it to go over the next one below it?

Comment: Yes this is exactly what i want!

Comment: So for now, duplicating the input when typing is irrelevant? I'm not sure why the limit of the input is 9 characters. Maybe Ayush Sharma's answer is what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes as I said i simplified the function for the fiddle. No its not what i meaned.

Comment: I just editet my question to show you guys the problem better.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134048/discussion-between-lostluke-and-gezzasa).

Answer (score 0):

Updated JS fiddle, try this, i have updated CSS part in your code

https://jsfiddle.net/wp3wvuj2/2/

```
.main_input {
   width: 209px;
   top: 70px;   
  margin: auto;
  margin-bottom:30px;
  /* position: relative */ 
  overflow: auto;
  height:216px; //Give some height always to apply overflow auto
}

.main_start {
width: 100%;
margin: auto;
/* position: absolute */ //Not required
bottom: 20px;
font-family: Pamela;
font-size: 36px;
text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for me... I want the Start button positioned at the bottom. So for example when you open the page on a laptop you could make 20 player before it goes scrollable; in a phone only 5.

Comment: so add height with the help of media queries for different resolution and make the position fixed for start div

Answer (score 0):

I've only changed the styles on class main-input

```
.main_input {
    width: 226px;
    height: 234px;
    top: 70px;
    margin: auto;
    margin-bottom:30px;
    position: relative;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

EDIT:

Please note for this solution to be able to work, I needed to remove the Top and Bottom positions of some elements as they were breaking the layout. Please use Margins or Paddings to get that styling you desire.

This now works to scroll once the space runs out on the page.

https://jsfiddle.net/wp3wvuj2/5/

Comment: Don't solves my problem...
It gets scrollable on height 234px independently from the resolution

Comment: Do you have another idea?

Comment: @lostluke, sorry for not replying. I have an idea but it will require a lot of Javascript where on each page load, you work out the size of the screen, minus the height of the other elements(logo and start button) and then add that as a min height to your input container.

Comment: @lostluke I've edited my answer. Please check the fiddle and see if you're happy. Please note I've done minimal layout css changes too. Explained in my edit.